# How to remove case sensitivity for Table and column names in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I'm new to Sybase and I really find it annoying to write sql with appropriate case for table names and column names. For eg, if the table name is 'Employee' I can't query as,

```
select * from employee
```

Is there a way to change this behavior in Sybase?

I don't want to change the sort order or anything. I'm looking for a hack to bypass this issue.

Cheers!!

Comment: have you tried looking at http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Thdbcs.htm

Comment: this is server level configuration and you can not change it unless of course if you are DBA

Comment: @Satya Yea but it doesn't help how to disable this. I really hate this behaviour of Sybase

Comment: Again, don't hate sybase for this. Ask DBAs to change the config

Comment: @Satya - that link is for Sybase IQ, not for Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is a result of the servers sort order.  This is a server level setting, not a database level setting, so the change will affect all databases on the server.  Also if the database is in replication, all connected servers will need their sort order changed as well.

Changing the sort order will also require you to rebuild all the indexes in your system.

Here is the correct documentation on selecting or changing character sets and sort orders.

[Configuring Character Sets, Sort Orders, and Languages](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1600/doc/html/san1360629204598.html)

As mentioned in the comments, it will require DBA level access and the server will have to be restarted before changes will take affect.

Comment: I'm looking for a hack by which I dont have to change the sort order. Maybe a tool which can detect the tables case irrespective of the sql's case.

Comment: @mani_nz There isn't one.  The only thing I've seen done before is to ensure all objects follow a strict naming policy of all Uppercase or all Lowercase.  If you don't have a naming policy in place, it could be time to create one, and rename the existing objects to match that policy.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out in the other responses, this is a server-level configuration setting, which can be changed. 
However, what is not mentioned is that in ASE, case-sensitivity applies equally to identifiers as well as to data comparison. So if you configure a case-insensitive sort order as discussed here, the effect will also be that 'Johnson' is now consider equal to 'JOHNSON' - and this could potentially cause trouble in applications. 
In this sense, ASE is different from other databases where these two aspects of case-sensitivity are decoupled.

Comment: All these makes me wonder why Sybase ASE is chosen in the first place.

Comment: @mani_nz - It was chosen because Sybase ASE has a lower TCO than most other enterprise RDBMS.  Your problem is a configuration issue, not a Sybase issue.  You would likely have a similar problem on an Oracle DB if it were configured similarly.